# How to output a template of detail post rightly?

Tags: angular, jsonplaceholder

I'm write project for learning Angular. My project displays posts from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/. I want to display a detailed post template (on localhost:3000/posts/1 for example). I am getting a specific post at posts.service.ts in method getById. Now I have an error - "Type 'Subscription' has no properties in common with type 'Post'". But I don't know how to fix that. Where is my mistake? How to fix that? How to output a template ({{ post.title }}) rightly?

All project here: [posts project](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-williamson-m68wx?file=/src/app/post.service.ts)

post.service.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

export interface Post {
  title: string;
  userId?: number;
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class PostService {
  private _postsURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public fetchPosts(page: number, itemsPerPage: number): Observable<Post[]> {
    let posts = this.http.get<Post[]>(`${this._postsURL}/posts`);

    return this.getPageItems(posts, page, itemsPerPage);
  }

  private getPageItems(
    posts: Observable<Post[]>,
    page: number,
    itemsPerPage: number
  ): Observable<Post[]> {
    return posts.pipe(
      map((u) => {
        let startIndex = itemsPerPage * (page - 1);
        return u.slice(startIndex, startIndex + itemsPerPage);
      })
    );
  }

  getById(id: number) {
    let post = this.http
      .get<Post[]>(`${this._postsURL}/posts/${id}`)
      .subscribe();

    return post;
  }
}
```

post.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from "@angular/router";
import { Post, PostService } from "../post.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-post",
  templateUrl: "./post.component.html"
})
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
  post: any;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private postsService: PostService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.post = this.postsService.getById(+params.id);
    });
  }
}
```

post.component.html:

```
<div>
    post component
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: @Bozhinovski, thanks a lot for your answer! This code works good in codesandbox, but in my build I have a mistake: "src/app/post/post.component.html:3:27 - error TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.  <h1>{{ (post | async )?.title }}</h1>". I think mistake in "post: any;" in in post.component.ts, Do you know to fix that? Thank you!

Comment: @Bozhinovski, What should be in the meaning of initializer post: Observable<Post>? Now, I have an error: "Property 'post' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor." Do you know to fix that? Thank you!

Comment: This is another question. You can eventually try adding question mark to variable -> post?: Observable<Post>;

Comment: @Bozhinovski, Okay, thank you! I'm marked your answer. https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-wescoff-hdhem in codesandbox works fine, but in my build I have an error Property 'title' does not exist on type 'Post[]'. <h1>{{ (post | async )?.title }}</h1> Why am I having a problem with this?

Comment: Remove array from. Post[] -> Post

Comment: @Bozhinovski, I remove array from. Post[] -> Post in getById method, and it works. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change several things in your code in order for this work and follow best practices.
The async pipe will also take care of unsubscribing from the observable when the component is destroyed so you don't have to manually unsubscribe from it.

Also it is more efficient in terms of change detection.

In you post.service change getById to return observable:

Another thing in case you want to see structured HTML json response, you can use "< pre></ pre>" tag.

```
getById(id: number): Observable<Post> {
    return this.http.get<Post>(`${this._postsURL}/posts/${id}`);
}
```

And post.component.html to:

```
<div>
  post component
  <h1>{{ (post | async )?.title }}</h1>
  <pre>{{ (post | async) }}</pre> // you can see structured json
</div>
```

Please check fixed sample:

https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-drake-zgri7?file=/src/app/post/post.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this. I would propose below solution:

In service, you can return observable. Here you are typecasting return as Observable to returning subscription. So change it to: Also, it is returning single Post instead of Post[]. Please validate.

```
getById(id: number): Observable<Post> {
   let post = this.http.get<Post>(`${this._postsURL}/posts/${id}`);
    return post;
}
```

In html you can use async pipe to get the value of title as:

```
<h1>{{ (post | async)?.title }}</h1>
```